Create a non mixed array from a union of types
I have a union of types and I'd like to create a utility type that creates a non mixed array type from it, e.g.:
type MyType = string | number
type ArrayOfMyType = ToArray<MyType> // -> string[] | number[], but not (string | number)[]


I was curious about the solution proposed by Lishugupta652. Even if it is clearly AI generated it works and i think it is more important to understand why than just paste some snippet and expect the answer to be accepted.
The way it works has something to do with type distribution, which is defined like this in this article :

Type distribution [...] is a feature of a compiler that applies
conditionals to each item of generic union types, not to a union as a
whole.

If we use a generic union type directly to construct a new type, like in this example :
type ToArray<T> = T[];
type MyArray = ToArray<string | number>

T[] will result to (string | number)[] because the whole union type is used, regardless of the items it contains
Here comes the extends property. Using extends will apply the condition on each items, where T will be the current iteration. The type is being distributed, therefore we can construct the wanted type
type ToArray<T> = T extends unknown ? T[] : never;
type MyArray = ToArray<string | number> // string[] | number[]

There is indeed one exception with the boolean type (i searched if there was another but apparently), because a boolean works like a literal type containing two value, true and false, therefore if we distribute the generic union type, we will get one iteration for the type true and one for the type false. So for this specific case adding an exception works
type ToArray<T> = T extends boolean ? boolean[] : T extends any ? T[] : never;

type ArrayOfMyType = ToArray<string | number| boolean>; // string[] | number[] | boolean

For both types true and false the returned type will be boolean[], because for both of them extends boolean ? will be true

Hi, thanks for your answer. Totally agree with not promoting IA generated responses (this is obviously based on an interpretation and I apologize to Lishugupta652 if he didn't actually used IA).

type MyType = string | number;

type ToArray<T> = T extends boolean ? boolean[] : T extends any ? T[] : never;

type ArrayOfMyType = ToArray<MyType>; // string[] | number[]

typescript playground

this doesn't work if one of the union types is a boolean, as it takes true or false as different  types, and doesn't allow to mix them, i.e. [false, true] would not be valid. Also this answer is suspiciously similar to what different IA sites answer, please, don't do that if you did

if you want to handle boolean types specifically then just use below.
type ToArray<T> = T extends boolean ? boolean[] : T extends any ? T[] : never;

https://i.sstatic.net/V6EiDlth.png

The playground link only points to a photo...

Ok, that seems to work, but I wonder if there could be other similar use cases, and therefore, more conditions should be added to the ToArray definition.. is this robust or not so much?
